# Thumbnails fadein fadeout specific div fade issues

Tags: jquery, hover, fadein, fadeout, fadeto

I am using this code to hide and show a div based on which thumbnail you rollover;

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.infodiv').hide();
    $(".website_thumbs a").hover(
    function(){
       var name = $(this).attr("name");
       $(".infodiv").stop();
        $("."+name).fadeIn();
    },
    function(){
       var name = $(this).attr("name");
        $("."+name).fadeTo(7000,1).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

The script gets the name attribute from the thumbnail and displays the div with the corresponding class. Each div shares the .infodiv class but also has a class unique to each thumbnail.

The functionality is basically where I want it but when you scroll over the thumbnails fast some of the divs get stuck in a kind of half faded-in state and stop working unless i roll over them once - then they slow fade in and they are usable again.

I am a bit new to jQuery and would appreciate any help.

Comment: so you do not want to "fadein" when you scroll over the thumbnails fast? If that is the case, you can probably introduce some delay. Not sure how we could do that though. if the user hovers the mouse over the thumbnail for more than "n number of seconds" then display the div. something like that.

Comment: see the following stackoverflow link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435732/delay-jquery-hover-event

Comment: No I want it to work the way it is - the fadeto is there to delay the fadeout, but it's not causing the issue, it does it even without it in there. The problem is if you go too fast between multiple thumbnails the whole thing stops working. What seems to be happening is some of the fadedin/out divs get stuck halfway through the fadein/out - so they no longer work until you mouseover them then mouseout and after a few seconds they will disappear and work again.

Comment: By the way the reason I added the fadeTo delay is so that it doesn't show any blank white space when going from thumbnail to thumbnail. Basically I want it to look like one div fades into the next.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the $(".infodiv").stop(); line--that stops all the infodivs from animating.

Comment: I added that because without it it would not display a previous div once I rolled over the next until the animation was finished playing.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html.) plugin.