# Adding delay to mouse out function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one drop down menu,

```
<ul>
<li><a>link 1</a>
<ul><li><a>link 1</a></li></ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I am using the following JS to use hover and show child menus.

I want to add delay to the mouse out function (when the class of the LI removed) about 500ms,

```
 $('li').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('over');
    }, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('over');
  });
```

Please do needful in this.

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delay jquery hover event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435732/delay-jquery-hover-event)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$('li').hover(function(){
  var timer = $(this).data('timer');
  if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
  $(this).addClass('over');
}, function(){
  var li = $(this);
  li.data('timer', setTimeout(function(){ li.removeClass('over'); }, 500));
});
```

This clears any timeout when hovering over it (in case you hover, leave, hover back you need to check this) and sets a 500ms delay when leaving the hover, storing the timeout ID on the li itself using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('over');
    }, function(){
    setTimeout(function(){$(this).removeClass('over')}, 500);
  });
```