# Hover Intend not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I'm not that good with js. How do I get this to work with hoverIntent?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav > li > a').hover(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
            $('#nav li ul').slideUp(800);
            $(this).next().slideToggle(800);
            $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I have try searching around, but just not too sure how to do it. It's basically working now with hover. but how do I add in .hoverIntent into the code.

[This is the Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/leslie20/Fmu8Y/)

I can't just change .hover to .hoverIntent right?

Comment: Can you upload the same example in jsFiddle.

Comment: Hi, here;s the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/leslie20/Fmu8Y/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For hoverIntend, see jQuery plugin: 
http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html
(You just have to download the minified version and import it to your application: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js).

Here the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fmu8Y/1/

Also a helpful link: [Delay jquery hover event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435732/delay-jquery-hover-event)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nav > li > a').hoverIntent(function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')){
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp(800);
      $(this).next().slideToggle(800);
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
   }
 }, function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
      $(this).next().slideUp(800);
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    }  
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Sorry, my code is already working. But i need it to add in the hoverIntend function.

Thanks for helping!!

Comment: Yes, when I saw your code it was already too late. =) The code above was just an example.

Comment: Thanks santedicola! But any idea how to add the hoverIntent function?

Comment: Sorry, now I get it. Have you tried this jQuery plugIn? http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: I've updated the answer, now using hoverIntent. See the jsFiddle. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Santedicola, there's a bit of error in your code. I managed to solved it thou. Thanks for your help!!

http://jsfiddle.net/leslie20/Fmu8Y/2/

Comment: Sorry, how do I add in the var config to control the sensitive?