# Only Make AJAX Call if Mouse Hover For 2 Seconds

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an AJAX call that I only what to make if I've moused over a certain element for 2 seconds and to NOT make the call otherwise.  I've tried to use setTimeout but it makes the call anyways. How can I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
$('tr').mouseenter(function(){

    $( this ).next("#ticket_summary").show();
    var context = $( this ).next("#ticket_summary");
    var ticket_id = $( this ).next("#ticket_summary").data("id");
    var url = "/support/ticket_description/" + ticket_id.toString();
    console.log(url);
    setTimeout(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            context.find('#ticket_summary_description').html(data[1]['fields']['text']);
            context.find('#ticket_summary_last_comment').html(data[2]['fields']['text']);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            context.find('#ticket_summary_description').html('error');
            context.find('#ticket_summary_last_comment').html('error');
        }
    });
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Look here for some suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435732/delay-jquery-hover-event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that you have to cancel the timeout with `clearTimeout` if the user moves away.

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/wdxbk4fL/)

- To detect when the user "un-hovers" use: [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)
- To only handle the event once we use [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)
- To cancel the timeout use: [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout)

The code should be something like:

```
$('.the-element').on('mouseenter', function (e) {
     var timeout = setTimeout(function () { ... }, 2000 );
     $(e.target).one('mouseleave', function () {
         clearTimeout(timeout)'
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work.

**HTML:**

```
<a id='test'>LINK</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#test").mouseenter(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"test.php",
            success:function(){
                alert("success");
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("ERROR");
            }
        });
    },5000);
});
```

**jsFiddle:**

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmcov7ev/)