# How can I control my hover event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

I'm trying to show an overlay div when '.menu' is hovered over. I've used hover to show the div (hidden first with CSS), the mouseleave to reset it. How can I do it so the mouse needs to be on the menu for a couple of seconds for it to show, so if its just rolled over quickly it doesnt do anything. I know I can do this with delay() but if i go over the button quickly 5 times, the screen flashes 5 times with the overlay. How can i make it only do it once and then terminate.

Thanks.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {

        $(".menu").hover(function() {
            $(".page-overlay").delay(600).fadeIn(200);
        });

        $(".menu").mouseleave(function() { 
            $(".page-overlay").fadeOut(200); 
        });

});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delay jquery hover event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435732/delay-jquery-hover-event)

Comment: I voted to close this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435732/delay-jquery-hover-event -- I think the advice is good; while it's possible to solve this with `setTimeout`/`clearTimeout`, it can be hard to get it right and people seem happy with the hoverIntent plugin.

Comment: @LinusGustavLarssonThiel shouldn't all answers to questions be void of recommendations from third party software?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`, check example bellow.

> I can do this with delay() but if i go over the button quickly 5 times, the screen flashes 5 times with the overlay

Using the `clearTimeout()` function in `hoverOut()` in example bellow will resolve this problem.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var menu_hover_timer;
    $(".page-overlay").hide();

    $( ".menu" ).hover(
        function() {
            menu_hover_timer = setTimeout(function(){
                $(".page-overlay").fadeIn(200);
            },1000); //wait 1 seconds
        }, function() {
            clearTimeout(menu_hover_timer)
        }
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='menu'>
  Menu (Stay hover 1 second HERE)
</div>
<div class='page-overlay'>
  page overlay div
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `hover` method accommodates for the mouse entering *and* leaving events, so you don't really need to make an explicit `mouseleave` event handler.

[`hover`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp) works like this:

```
$( ... ).hover(function(){
    // Here is the mouse entering function
},
function(){
    // Here is the mouse exiting function
});
```

So you can adjust your code to something like this:

```
$(".menu").hover(function() {
    $(".page-overlay").delay(600).fadeIn(200);
},
function(){
    $(".page-overlay").fadeOut(200);
});
```