# add transparency on hover on a div but with time delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my div to become partially transparent 1 second after I hover cursor on it. When no longer hovering I want it to return to its default full opacity immediately without any time delay.
I know very very javascript so I don't know how to do this.

Any help much appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: That delay could be bad for the user experience, any reason why you want it? Having said that, this question has been asked before and answered well here, You can use hoverintent plugin to accomplish it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435732/delay-jquery-hover-event

Comment: @NathanielFlick that delay is good in this case trust me but can u help

Comment: Yes I updated my answer above. Remember delaying hover doesn't work on mobile devices since there is no "hover" state for them, only touch/click.

Comment: @NathanielFlick i will check it out but would prefer a plugin less solution

Comment: There are some no plugin solutions on that answer, have a read there. The one that talks about checking if there's a timer running and killing it first before starting a new timer on a new hover. This keeps the timer time from being cumulative.

Comment: This is the non plugin solution from that link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/435793/4335939, change the "500" to "1000" for one second.

Comment: thanks so much bro by the way in case you are wondering i am trying to mimic functionality on https://www.greats.com/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131437/discussion-between-nathaniel-flick-and-usman-sikander).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you shouldn't use js in this case. [CSS Transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) would be better, cause they are smoother and more efficient than js/jQuery animations.

Below you have example with 2 seconds delay on hover.

```css
.btn{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
  transition: background 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.btn:hover{
  -webkit-transition: background 0.5s ease 2s;
  transition: background 0.5s ease 2s;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">Text</a>
```