# Cycle through hover state based on timer jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, delay

There are a few posts on this topic including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435732/delay-jquery-hover-event), but none that are specific enough to adapt to my setup.

I need to chain delays together to 'cycle' through the hover states of these four divs: `#sectiontrigger1`, `#sectiontrigger2`, `#sectiontrigger3`, `#sectiontrigger4` based on a timer of **3200 ms**.

I also need this sequence to loop, for example when the 4th (`#sectiontrigger4`) div timer ends the cycle resets and the hover state is applied to the first div (`#sectiontrigger1`) again. This loop needs to repeat indefinitely.

Can this be achieved with jQuery?

Comment: you have tried anything ?

Comment: @SudharsanS I'm not sure how I would trigger the hover states sequentially so I'm reading through jQuery documentation to try to piece something together - so far I've realised I might have to switch the ID's to classes and use .addClass/.removeClass to apply the hover state and now I'm looking for a way to trigger multiple timers and then reset them all - JS/jQuery is new to me so I'm swimming in uncharted waters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/0vpht72f/

```js
$('div').mouseenter(function(){
 $(this).css({opacity:0.5});
});

$('div').mouseleave(function(){
 $(this).css({opacity:1});
});

var cnt = 1;
var prevCnt = 4;

setInterval(function(){
 $('#div' + prevCnt).mouseleave();
 $('#div' + cnt).mouseenter();
  prevCnt++;
  cnt++;
  if(cnt > 4){
   cnt = 1;
  }
  
  if( prevCnt > 4){ 
   prevCnt = 1;
  }
}, 3200);
```

```css
div{
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
Div 1
</div>
<div id="div2">
Div 2
</div>
<div id="div3">
Div 3
</div>
<div id="div4">
Div 4
</div>
```

I guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you so much, this would have been virtually impossible with my current level of JS knowledge, really appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome @VDesign :)